# inserting data in assotiation table with three columns in flask sqlachemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have two Tables which had many-to may relation ship in flask alchemy:

```
users_chats_association = db.Table(
    "users_chats",
    db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id")),
    db.Column("chat_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("chats.id")),
    db.Column('some_number', db.String)
)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    chats = db.relationship(
        "Chat", secondary=users_chats_association, back_populates="users"
    )


class Chat(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "chats"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    users = db.relationship(
        "User", secondary=users_chats_association, back_populates="chats"
    )
```

If I want to insert value I use such code:

```
user = User(name='first_user')
db.session.add(user)
chat = Chat(title='First_chat')
db.session.add(chat)
chat.users.append(user)
db.session.commit()
```

But this code insert in assotiation table in first two column. How should I insert value in third 'some_number' Column?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

Comment: I also can not solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
id_of_need_user = (User.query.filter(User.name=='first_user').first())

update_query = update(users_chats_association).\
    where(users_chats_association.c.user_id==id_of_need_user.id).\
    values(some_number='12345888')

db.session.execute(update_query)
db.session.commit()
```